# How do I have a field (Table.EmployeeNo) in Crystal Reports only return data for users that are active in a parameter?

Tags: crystal-reports

I report I'm in the process of repairing that adds up times for employees. It has two parameters; a date range parameter, and an "employee number" parameter that allows for multiple values. Crystal Reports stores a maximum of 1000 values for parameters, but we've just exceeded 1000 employees in our system. Not all of these employees are active. I would like to sort out any employee numbers from showing up in the input box for the parameter by whether or not they are listed as active.

I have a field (Table.EmployeeNo) that holds employee numbers that I have a field (Table.IsActive) that holds a "Y" or "N" value based on whether or not a user is active. How do I tell Crystal Reports to not give me any data from Table.EmployeeNo where Table.IsActive = "N" before it would prompt for parameters?

I don't need to suppress a field or anything like that. I need to make sure there is space for Crystal Reports to list a maximum of 1000 ACTIVE users as opposed to reaching it's maximum with inactive users cluttering the parameter data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my guess you are generating the report by joining the tables in database expert... so you are getting all employee numbers irrespective of active or not.

So the solution would be instead of table joinings you create a command and write your query with where clause having `where Table.IsActive = "N"`

Now in report create a dynamic parameter so that the employees that are active are retrived.

Edit........................

Example command change as per your requirement

Select *from table where table.IsActive="N"

Now place the command in command part and in design create the dynamic parameter

Comment: I have a pretty novice level of skill with Crystal. How do I create a command and write a query? Does that have to do with code in SQL?

Comment: Yes you need to write an sql command with proper where clause and use it in command part instead of joining tabes...which will work

Comment: You can but in this your parameter will active and inactive both...if you need only active then try with sql command

Comment: Okay, thanks for all the help Siva. Can you send me an example of an SQL command that would do something like this? I don't touch SQL at all normally.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I'm going to have to look up SQL syntax. Your example code is returning a bunch of 'can't be bound' etc errors.Thank you for all your help though. This should solve my problem. I'll post my code when I figure it out.

Comment: This is just an sample query for your problem.... one trick if you are unable to write a query is to first link all tables in crystal and then place fields in crystal design after that go for show sql query... then pick the query and add where clause to that and use the same query in comand... this reduce your effort in writing sql..let me know how it goes

Comment: It appears to be still pulling all the inactives in the parameter field. I may have to make a view.

Comment: Both are same brother.. Use the same SQL that you are using in View in Command.. It is just the differnet way to doing the things.

Comment: Okay, well I did:
    SELECT * FROM USERLIST
    WHERE ISACTIVE='Y' but now it's taking forever to run the report and not working properly in general. It's just far, far too slow and sometimes doesn't even complete.

Comment: Its nothing to do with crystal reports...check the database side performance issues

Comment: Okay. I got it working. I needed to make a view in SQL. When I used the Add Command, the report took about fifteen minutes to run and didn't return any values. I copy and pasted the query in to the actual database view and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Create a dynamic parameter based on a command, which retrieves  active users